# Cambiar versiones Python en la ruta /usr/local/bin/

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, packages

Estoy tratando de dejar atrás la versión 3.10 de python que instalé en su día, y regresar a la anterior 3.9, ya instalada, con la que funcionaba totalmente.

En la ruta ***/usr/local/lib*** he conseguido, supuestamente, utilizar python3.9 pero al lanzar el comando
`python3 -m site --user-site`
me sigue apareciendo ***/home/xxxx/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages***

**¿Hay alguna manera de cambiar totalmente a la version 3.9?**
Estoy trabajando con Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)

Con `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` :

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      27 May 14 22:21 /usr/bin/python -> /etc/alternatives/python3.9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3637096 Mar  8 19:40 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Mar  8 19:40 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1018 Oct 28  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsondiff
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    3661 Oct 28  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsonpatch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1342 May  2  2016 /usr/bin/python3-jsonpointer
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     398 Nov 15  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsonschema
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Mar 10 17:46 /usr/bin/python3.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Mar 10 17:46 /usr/bin/python3.6-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 Mar 10 17:46 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 Mar 10 17:46 /usr/bin/python3.6m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.6m-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      17 Oct 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m-config -> python3.6m-config
```

Y con `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*` (**Aquí si aparece 3.10**):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       10 May 12 11:29 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> python3.10
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       17 May 12 11:29 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> python3.10-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 20185304 May 12 11:28 /usr/local/bin/python3.10
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3090 May 12 11:29 /usr/local/bin/python3.10-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19191072 Jun 21  2021 /usr/local/bin/python3.9
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3087 Jun 21  2021 /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config
```

**¿Se recomienda eliminar las líneas del python 3.10 para ver si así accede sólo a las de 3.9?**

*Pretendo no depender de un virtual environment ya que sólo se trata de una única app (flask)*

Al entrar a la consola: `python3`

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python 3.10.0 (default, May 12 2023, 11:25:21) [GCC 7.5.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/apps/venv/bin', '/usr/local/lib/python3.9', '/usr/local/lib/python310.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.10', '/usr/local/lib/lib-dynload']
```

Comment: si eliminas la linea que hace el link de python3 a python3.10 te ariesgas a cargarte el sistema. Como se te ha recomendado en la anterior pregunta, la solucion es que deberias usar virtual environments para ejecutar tus aplicaciones. Pero si quieres reconfigurar tu sistema manualmente eliminando enlaces simbolicos tu mismo. Ha un backup de tus datos antes. Y entonces puedes llinkar python3 y python3-config a python3.9

Comment: No deberías cambiar ningún enlace del sistema a mano. Veo que el enlace  `/usr/bin/python` lo tienes enlazado a python 3.9 en _alternatives_.  Supongo que tendrás que reconfigurar el python 3.9, algo como `dpkg-reconfigure python-3.9` para linux basados en paquetes .deb

Comment: ¿cómo y desde donde tendría que lanzar el comando `dpkg-reconfigure python-3.9` ? En cuanto al enlace a python3.9 en alternatives, ¿qué quiere decir? @ChemaCortes

Comment: te puedes evitar todo eso con el uso de `venv` o mejor aun, de `conda`

Comment: dpkg-reconfigure es un comando de distribuciones tipo debian/ubuntu que hay que ejecutar como root. alternatives es un alias que crea tu distribución para seleccionar una de las alternativas entre las que puede instalar. Busca información sobre el comando `update-alternatives`.